# How to add an exception to AdBlock in Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, adblock

I use the AdBlock Plus for IE extension but I can't really configure it.

I can only *enable or disable* it, or see its information panel:

```
Name:                          Adblock Plus for IE Browser Helper Object
Publisher:                     Eyeo GmbH
Type:                          Browser helper object
Architecture:                  32-bit and 64-bit
Version:                       1.5.0.0
```

Can you tell me how I could add a site to the exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the Status bar in IE, and click the ABP icon there. This opens the following web page:

```
C:\Program Files\Adblock Plus for IE\html\templates\index.html
```

... where you can configure the exceptions.

Comment: Thanks, I could've never figured out that tha status bar is the place where I should look :)

Comment: YW Nestor. Atleast for me, the extension showed a message box asking me to enable the Status bar, and that's how I know  ;) Cheers.